# How to remove a half-space from Persian characters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

*I want to remove half-space in Persian characters with javascript and replace it with a hyphen.*

for example, I want to change :

```
راه‌کارهای پیشرفته‌ی برنامه‌نویسی
```

with:

```
راه-‌کارهای-پیشرفته‌ی-برنامه‌نویسی
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: You can use something like this

var original='را کارهای پیشرفتی برنام نویسی';

document.write(original.replace(' ','-'));

but problem is that there are language processor works on these script and could result a different text when you print them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this function :

```
function(value) {
 const str = value.split('');
 str.forEach((item, index) => {
  const charCode = item.charCodeAt(0);
  if (charCode === 32 || charCode === 8204) {
    str[index] = '-';
  }
 });
 value = str.join('');
 return value;
}
```